# USB power on arduino digitalRead is normal, but, gives error when using buck(step down) converter

Tags: power

I am using arduino for `digitalRead()`. i've been using `INPUT_PULLUP`, and when using USB power, all seems normal. but, when i switched to  power supply and buck converter(12v to 5v), the `digitalRead()` randomly change. why is that?

Comment: Impossible to say without more details. Provide a circuit diagram including the models of components, info about where you feed the input power, and the code for a minimal application that exhibits the behavior.

Comment: Is the 12V to 5V output being applied to the barrel jack connector? That is too low a level for the onboard 5V regulator to work from. Connect that 5V to the 5V pin instead.

Comment: If you read the docs they advise against feeding 5V into the 5V pin. What I've done is to cut a USB cable and feed my regulated 5V into that. That way you get the benefits of the on-board power source selection and protection circuits. (The Arduino intelligently manages choosing between USB power and barrel connector power. If you feed 5V into the 5V pin directly then you have to remember to disconnect that before plugging in a USB cable to program the Arduino.)